# Symfony 5 / Docker connecting to MS SQL Server but getting MySQL error

Tags: php, sql-server, docker, symfony5

We're running Symfony 5 inside a docker container and connecting to a remote MSSQL Server database through the corporate vpn. Everyone on the team uses Macs and are able to connect to the remote database when testing on their own systems.

But I am working on Linux Mint 18.3 and get this error:

> An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver in
> vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php
> (line 128)

We are not trying to connect to a MySQL database anywhere in the code, so I'm not sure why Symfony/Doctrine would even look for that driver. All Symfony code and Docker config are in version control, so we are working from identical code. And I have an exact copy of the .env file that we all use.

So why can't I connect to the MSSQL Server database and why would I get a MySQL error when trying it?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem from a MySQL driver while I'm using MSSQL: `An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`.

Comment: In my case, I was using a custom name for my connection, but seems that some packages are not aware of `default_connection` in the `doctrine.yml` config. So I had to add a `default` connection as duplicate of my another connection.